# Getting around dots in "pretty urls"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actioncontroller

In my routes.rb I've got:

```
map.connect ':name',
            :controller => 'my_classes',
            :action => 'show'
```

And that works perfectly, so a url like this sends params like so:

```
http://localhost:30000/awesome
Parameters: {"name"=>"awesome"}
```

But if I have something like this I get this error:

```
http://localhost:30000/weak.sauce
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/weak.sauce" with {:method=>:get}):
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
map.connect ':name',
            :controller => 'my_classes',
            :action => 'show',
            :name => /[a-zA-Z\.]+/
```

or use whatever regular expression you want for the name. (The one I suggested should match any letter or dot combination - `weak.sauce`, `weak...sauce`, `.weak.sauce.`, etc.)

Comment: Perfect.  I really need to spend a week on regular expressions, I had a hunch the solution would include them.

Comment: in the regular expression you might want to escape the "." like so: \.

Comment: Since the dot is within a character class it doesn't need to be escaped.  Still escaping it won't hurt anything either.

Comment: True, I forgot (reaches for coffee ;-)